# Oneliner to detect camelcase variables

Tags: bash, grep, sed

I would like to insert some style tests as git hooks in order to stick with precise style rules.
How can I come up with a oneliner that detects and prints arbitrary camelcase variables like the following:

```
camelCasehere
or
camelCaseHere
or
camel_caseHere
```

Comment: Are these strings in variables or in a file. If in a file, do they occur on a line by themselves, or is the file a full program in some language?  How would you envisage matching only _variables_ in that source code in that case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about

```
/bin/grep -E '[a-z]{1,}[A-Z]'
```

This would require that at least one lowercase character is before an uppercase. This would match all your testcases.

If you want to also match something like `camel_Case` and **not** `Nocamelcase` you can use:

```
/bin/grep -E '([a-z]{1,}[A-Z])|(^.+[A-Z]{1,}[a-z])'
```

To test it yourself you can use something like:

```
cat <<EOF | /bin/grep -E '([a-z]{1,}[A-Z])|(^.+[A-Z]{1,}[a-z])'
NONMATCH                                                               
nonmatch
shouldMatch1
should_Match2
should_mAtch3
Non_match    
Non_MATCH
Should_mAtch4
Should_Match5
EOF
```

Comment: The second solution is the best suited.

Comment: `{1,}` is better written as `+` in EREs (shorter and more portable, EREs initially didn't have `{x,y}`), but anyway  `grep '[a-z][A-Z]'` would achieve the same thing.

Comment: What `[a-z]` matches (and in particular whether it matches some uppercase characters) depends on the system and locale. Using `[[:lower:]]` and `[[:upper:]]` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is useful for somebody, here you are a oneliner to detect PHP variables with Snake Case in code (assumes GNU `grep`):

```
grep -r --include='*.php' -E '\$[a-zA-Z]+_[a-zA-Z]' .
```

Comment: How would this pick up only _variables_?

Comment: PHP variables start with a dollar ($) char, and the regular expression has this consideration.

Comment: It misses variables like `$foo1_bar`